# Removing Cross Site scripting in Java

Tags: java, xss

I have some old project to maintain. When scanned for code quality with some tool, it is observed that code has lot of Cross Site scripting issues which I need to resolve. One of the issue is given below.

```
 public class Tester1 {

    public void doRecurrssion(JspWriter out, MyDTO dto){

        out.print("<table");
        out.print("<tr>");
        out.print("<td width='30><font face='Arial, Helvetica'>"+dto.getFirstName()+"</font><td>\n");
        out.print("<td width='30><font face='Arial, Helvetica'>"+dto.getLastName()+"</font><td>\n");
        out.print("</tr>");
        out.print("</table>");
    }
}
```

I am getting cross site scripting issue for 3rd & 4th **"out.print"** statement in above code. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the tool is protesting because you're taking a raw value (e.g. the return value of `getFirstName()`) and including it verbatim in the HTML page.

Most likely the warning will go away if you protect yourself against XSS by HTML encoding the values, for example by using the [OWASP Java Encoder](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder) library:

```
out.print("<td width='30><font face='Arial, Helvetica'>" 
    + Encode.forHtml(dto.getFirstName()) + "</font><td>\n");
out.print("<td width='30><font face='Arial, Helvetica'>" 
    + Encode.forHtml(dto.getLastName()) + "</font><td>\n");
```

Comment: How will it work for below html code `<title><%=myForm.getName() %></title>`

Comment: @AbhishekNaswale: There are some JSP examples [in the documentation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project#tab=Use_the_Java_Encoder_Project).